# How to retrieve Gmail integration changes in VS Code

Tags: vs-code

I am making a change in the "Publisher Layout Assignment" in the "Gmail Integration and Sync". How do I retrieve this change in my VS code ? What should I include in the package file ?
[image]

Comment: It's probably in the `layoutAssignment` tag in profile and permission set.